# Would it be feasible to extend shake to being a configuration tool too?

Tags: shake-build-system

In the vein of Puppet/Chef; I would really like to use Shake for more than just local builds. I think the principles of Shake are abstract enough (I haven't dug deep though to know) that it could be used as the foundation for a larger configuration build tool.

Comment: I'm also interested in having strongly typed system deployment. Have you finally given a try to use shake as configuration management tool?

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I don't know much about Chef/Puppet, beyond a quick read of the project websites and Wikipedia.*

I think the dependency principles are abstract enough, even things like file rules are not built in. You would probably want to create a number of custom Rule instances for the types of configuration.

However, it seems like Puppet/Chef have a lot of pieces to them beyond just a dependency system, which would require reimplementing. Shake could be used as a basis to build a tool, but there would still be quite a lot of code left to write.